# Why does my roblox gui show in the testing area of studio but not in the game

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I have made a lot of progress on my game and my friend wanted to try it. So I joined the game on roblox through my profile to make sure it worked. I joined the game just to see that none of my guis were there. I am using scale for the size. I will provide my scripts if requested.

Comment: Where did you put the guis when you were testing them in Studio? Did they show up when you tested in Studio? Did you remember to publish the game before you and your friend played it on the website? When you join the game, are there any errors in the console when you type, "/console"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Publish the game again after making changes on Roblox?[image: How to Publish Game]

It is hard to help because I don't have a lot of info.